# How can I improve the design of my electronic speed controller?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, mosfet-driver, atmega328p

We have a brushless motor with the following characteristics (Slow(8T)):
[image]

For that motor, we are developing an electronic speed controller using the hall sensors. The microcontroller is an atmega328p and we are generating a PWM frequency of 8kHz in the low MOSFETs with a 6-step commutation.

The problem is that this configuration generates high currents (4 A in the source and 10 A in each phase) and in a short time of motor operation, the MOSFETS start to heat up.

I would like to know if the problem is in the design of the controller, the frequency of the PWM, or something that we are not considering to improve the performance of the controller.

Here is the schematic:
[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I improve the design of my electronic speed controller?

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have "shoot-through" which occurs if both top and bottom MOSFET are on at the same time?

Comment: Which Gate driver ICs are you using? What is the motor supply voltage? Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: What MOSFETs and what gate drivers are you using?  What made you choose 1 kΩ gate resistors?

Comment: May not be related but I wouldn't be using such slow diodes in the driver bootstrap circuit.

Comment: @BrianDrummond What can of diodes could you recommend

Comment: @evildemonic The MOSFETS are IRFZ44N AND the gate drivers are IR2110. The resistor value was chosen arbitrarily, if you have some advice to choose it correctly I would appreciate it. Here are the datasheets of the MOSFETS and gate drivers. Thanks.   MOSFETS: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/68619/IRF/IRFZ44N.html      DRIVERS: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/323402/IRF/IR2110.html

Comment: @BruceAbbott The motor has a nominal voltage of 48V, but we were testing it at 24V. Also, we have an oscilloscope but for pandemic reasons we couldn't use it.

Comment: @Transistor In each step, we turn off all the MOSFETS for 25 microseconds. Then we turn on the gates that correspond to the hall configuration.

Comment: For a simple shoot through test, try running the motor controller without the motor attached. If there isn't any shoot through the supply current drawn will be quite low. The turn on/off characteristics of the FETs will be a little different B/C there's no load current but bad shoot through conditions will be easy to spot and troubleshoot. All you need is a multi meter or a bench power supply with a current meter.

Comment: The diodes you have in your power stage seem a bit odd. The 1N4004 assuming the schematic has the correct part number won't be carrying much of the load current during the dead time. The FET body diode will be. If you look at the datasheet graphs for the FET and diode, at 1V the FET carries the full 10A while the diode passes only 2A. Most MOSFET based bridges don't bother including diodes unless you want to add schottkys or something.

Comment: After doing some rough calculations, 10A should give you (per half bridge) 1.05W conduction losses and 4W diode losses during dead time plus a little bit of capacitive losses that likely aren't significant. The 25µs dead time is increasing your losses significantly. At 8kHz you have 125µs per cycle and you're spending 50µs (2 switching transitions) with the FETs off. your losses would be below 2W if you could get rid of most of that dead time.

Comment: If you're trying to do cooling with no heat sink (or a tiny one) that's my advice. If you have a big metal heatsink and the transistors are still getting hot then it's something else.